# Spark chat-program can't find my JRE

Tags: java

I want to use the chat program Spark 2.5.8, but I got two problems when double clicking on spark.exe. The .Exe file is in my program files (x86) folder along with other files likes this:

[image]

First, the program complained I don't have a java JRE. I have 1.8, but apparently, it requires 1.5 or 1.6. So I installed the 1.6 JRE. Now I get another error:

[image]

I set a system variable on pc as folows:

Name: EXE4J_JAVA_HOME
Value: C:\Progra~1\Java\jre6\bin\Java.exe

Where Progra~1 expands to Program Files, which is where ym jre 1.6 resides.

What is going wrong?

Comment: I believe, the ANYTHING_JAVA_HOME env variable should point to the directory where your JRE is, or a `bin` directory inside, not directly to exe file.

Comment: @at8eqeq3 I tried both ......\jr6\bin\ and ....jre6\ but I get the same error for both.